# How to expand div wrapper width to fit the the table inside

Tags: css, datatables

I use the dataTable lib with external plugins and I would like that the wrapper width adjusts itself.

Even if the th width is important exceed the viewport with, the div width doesn't exceed 100%.

How can I expend the div wrapper to fit the table width ?

Here is an example :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
    .wrapper {
        background-color: red;
        /* width: 8000px; -> don't look for this kind of solution */
        width: auto;
        display: table;
    }

    .table {
        display: table-cell;
    }

    .table th {
        background-color: yellow;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        width: 4000px; /* -> note that I can't use the min-width trick because this property is set by an external jQuery plugin */
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Hello</th>
                    <th>World</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try this:

```
.table {
    /*width: 4000px;*/
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```